# Fluctuation interaction between two uncharged spheres

Tags: homework-and-exercises, forces, electrostatics, statistical-mechanics

**TL;DR:** The problem is to determine force, acting between two uncharged conducting spheres, induced by correlated fluctuations of charge densities in these spheres. I've got stucked along the way and don't know where the mistake is.

**Edit:** I've solved the problem and the answer is: $$F=18\cdot kT\frac {r^6}{R^7}$$ where $r$ is spheres' radius and $R$ is distance between them. I'll post solution here (as an answer) tomorrow.

**In a greater detail:** I'm trying to figure out quantitatively what is the force, acting between two uncharged conducting spheres and I've got stuck. It is not a kind of homework - it is just a simple act of curiosity.
I'd like to begin with several clarifications.
Firstly, let's consider where the interaction comes from. Imagine one uncharged metal sphere. Despite being uncharged, it has free electrons inside. So, there are thermal fluctuations of charge density in the sphere. One can think of them in terms of multipole moments: thermal fluctuations induce random dipole moment, quadrupole moment and so forth.
For simplification I'll consider only the first term in this row: fluctuations of dipole moment. Using formula:
$$
U=\frac{1}{2}\int \rho \varphi dV
$$
one can show that self energy of such a sphere in the first approximation is:
$$
U_{self}=\frac{1}{2}\frac{\mathbf{d}^2}{R_0^3}
$$
where $\mathbf{d}$ is dipole moment, $R_0$ is radius of the sphere.
Therefore, fluctuations are described statistically as follows:
$$
W(\mathbf{d})\sim e^{-\frac{U_{self}}{kT}}
$$
where $W(\mathbf{d})$ is probability of having a thermal induced dipole moment $\mathbf{d}$.
Now consider two uncharged spheres. The fluctuations in them are, of course, correlated. For example, imagine two spheres on the axis $Ox$ with the distance $R$ between them. Let it be so that due to fluctuations the induced dipole moment of the first sphere is directed upwards, along $Oy$ axis, and is equal to $\mathbf{d_1}$. The field this sphere would create is:
$$
\mathbf{E}=\frac{3(\mathbf{d_1}\cdot\mathbf{R})\mathbf{R}-\mathbf{d_1}R^2}{R^5}
$$
and in the position of the second sphere it would be directed downward, against the $Oy$ axis. Thus preferred direction for thermal fluctuations of the charge of the second spehere is created: the most probable state is that the dipole moment $\mathbf{d_2}$ of the second sphere is directed against $\mathbf{d_1}$. Therefore attraction must appear.
It seems clear that the dipole moment of one sphere would always be directed (most probably) so that attraction would exist.
However, when I try to describe this situation quantitatively, I face problems I don't know how to resolve. Please, take a look at my calculations and say, what's wrong.
Let's begin.
The full energy in system is given as follows:
$$
U(\mathbf{d_1},\mathbf{d_2})=\frac{1}{2}\frac{\mathbf{d_1}^2}{R_0^3}+\frac{1}{2}\frac{\mathbf{d_2}^2}{R_0^3}-\frac{3(\mathbf{d_1}\cdot\mathbf{R})(\mathbf{d_2}\cdot\mathbf{R})-\mathbf{d_1}\cdot\mathbf{d_2}R^2}{R^5}
$$
(for simplicity let's take the radiuses of these spheres equal).
The probability:
$$
W(\mathbf{d_1},\mathbf{d_2})\sim e^{-\frac{U(\mathbf{d_1},\mathbf{d_2})}{kT}}
$$
To be more exact, if I understand it right, one can say, that:
$$
dW(\mathbf{d_1},\mathbf{d_2})=A\cdot e^{-\frac{U(\mathbf{d_1},\mathbf{d_2})}{kT}}d\mathbf{d_1}d\mathbf{d_2}
$$
where $d\mathbf{d}=d\mathrm{d_x} \cdot d\mathrm{d_y} \cdot d\mathrm{d_z}$ and $A$ is normalization constant.
Using $\int dW=1$ we can find $A$ as:
$$
A=\frac{1}{\int e^{-\frac{U(\mathbf{d_1},\mathbf{d_2})}{kT}}d\mathbf{d_1}d\mathbf{d_2}}
$$
and then find average energy as follows:
$$
\bar{U}=\frac{\int U(\mathbf{d_1},\mathbf{d_2})\cdot e^{-\frac{U(\mathbf{d_1},\mathbf{d_2})}{kT}}d\mathbf{d_1}d\mathbf{d_2}}{\int e^{-\frac{U(\mathbf{d_1},\mathbf{d_2})}{kT}}d\mathbf{d_1}d\mathbf{d_2}}=-\frac{d\mathrm{ln}\int e^{-\frac{U(\mathbf{d_1},\mathbf{d_2})}{kT}}d\mathbf{d_1}d\mathbf{d_2}}{d(\frac{1}{kT})}
$$
Using the fact that energy is quadratic form of $\mathbf{d_1}$ and $\mathbf{d_2}$ one gets:
$$
\bar{U}=\frac{6kT}{2}
$$
as in any cases when energy is quadratic to "coordinates" (we have 6 degrees of freedom, and energy, equal to $kT/2$, corresponds to each one). So $\mathrm{grad}\:\bar {U}=\mathbf{0}$ and it looks like the interaction is absent.
**My questions are:**
What do I do wrong? Is there a lack in my qualitative understanding? Or there is a mathematical mistake in my calculations? Is this a well-known problem and if it is, I wonder if you can give me some links to the literature, where I can read about it.
I have several ideas on how to cope with difficulies.
It may be worth getting average of force between dipoles $\mathbf{F}=(\mathbf{d}\cdot \bigtriangledown )\mathbf{E}$, which looks the same as getting average only of the part of full energy in the system (skipping self-energy terms).

I'm sorry for my grammar mistakes, I hope they didn't bother you much.
Thank you for your attention and your advice.

Comment: You asked for literature, and I seem to remember that Israelachvili: "Intermolecular and Surface Forces" describes some quite similar systems: Interactions between thermally rotating (permanent) dipoles (you of course recover the dispersion/Keesom interaction, i.e. $\sim1/(Tr^6)$.

Comment: Thank you for your reply and literature recommendation, @alarge. Well, the answer in my case should definetly depend on temperature in a descending way too. However, as for intermolecular forces, London dispersion force looks like the most viable comparasent to the situation I mentioned, because it acts between molecules that has no charge or permanent dipole moment. However, it is described via quantum mechanics, while I try to work out simple classical solution.

Comment: It suddenly struck me, although I may be wrong, that isn't the quantity that you really want the (difference in) free energy, not internal energy? This is to say that I think you should compute the potential of mean force.

Comment: It definetly makes sense. The guaranteed way to calculate mean force is to calculate the integral $\mathbf{f}=\int {-\mathrm{grad}\:Ue^{-\beta U}d\mathbf{d_1}d\mathbf{d_2}}$ (here $\beta=1/kT$), which is not the same as firsly taking the average and then finding the gradient: $\mathbf{f}=-\mathrm{grad}\:\int {Ue^{-\beta U}d\mathbf{d_1}d\mathbf{d_2}}$ (that is the way I calculated the force previoiusly). The differnce comes from Leibniz's rule of differentiation. Unfortunately, I have no time to redo calculations now, but as soon as I do, I'll post results here.

Comment: @alarge, I suppose we are talking about the same thing, just in different language. Taking gradient at first will toss out internal terms in energy.

Comment: My point is slightly different. You say $F = -\nabla E$. This is not correct in the way I think you mean it. Suppose you have for the internal energy $dE = TdS - FdX$, where the latter term is the distance and the conjugate force. This is to say that $F = -\left.\frac{\partial E}{\partial X}\right)_S$. You don't want to be evaluating at fixed entropy (it's hard), so instead you ought to compute $F = -\left.\frac{\partial A}{\partial X}\right)_T$, $A$ being the (Helmholtz) free energy. I'm also not entirely convinced that all your terms are quadratic (but this is a different issue).

Comment: This is a nice problem!  But if the fluctuations of the two spheres are independent, why would you expect anything other than zero force on average?  I would guess that a fluctuation in one sphere must induce a fluctuation in the other in order to produce a nonzero average force, and it would depend on the polarizability of the materials.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, @pwf.
As you can see, there is a term if total energy, that depends on the relative directions of dipole moment. This term makes dipoles to be aligned oppositly in average and hence the force must appear.

Comment: Excuse me for non-answering for a long, @alarge. The point is that using $\mathbf{f}=\int -\mathbf{grad}\ Ue^{-\beta U}d\mathbf{d_1}d\mathbf{d_2}$ you can calculate force directly, without taking derivatives of some thermodynamical values.
Actually, I did calculation via the method I proposed and I have got the following answer:
$F=18kTr^6/R^7,$ where $r$ is a radius of spheres and $R$ is a distance between them.

Comment: @SpinningCat Did you by any chance post the same question to physicsforums.com? I seem to remember someone asking for help with the same question from Pathria's Stat. Mech. book around the same time as you posted this here. Either way, I think it would be beneficial for future readers if you wrote the full solution to your question as an answer and accepted it as the correct one (linking also to the physicsforums.com thread, if appropriate).

Comment: I tracked down the physicsforums.com thread: https://www.physicsforums.com/threads/average-force-between-electric-dipoles.765222/ The wording of the problem seems to be slightly different.

Comment: @alarge, I haven't posted this question anywhere but here. I'll post a solution I came up with here as soon as I have enough time for it.